# macOS Won't Show WiFi Login Page

Tags: macos, wifi, catalina, login

When connecting to hotel WiFi, the WiFi login page doesn't appear on macOS. When trying to go to a standard webpage I get an error about my network connection.

After reading a lot of documentation and articles online some common suggestions include:

- Navigating to http://neverssl.com or http://captive.apple.com in a web browser to see if a non-SSL site will trigger the login page to appear
- Try navigating to the router IP address (listed in System Preferences) in a web browser. This did redirect me to a different site, but that page had the same error as everything else.
- Flushing the DNS cache
- Restarting my computer
- Ensuring that there are no custom DNS Server addresses
- And more

None of these solutions triggered the login page, and none helped me establish a connection to the internet.

What is strange is going into recovery mode (the mode where you can reinstall macOS), and going into the Safari browser there shows the WiFi login page perfectly. But I don't want to stay in recovery mode forever, I want this to work in my normal system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On macOS Catalina (10.15.1), the solution for me was to manually open the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app` application in the Finder, which will trigger the standard application for displaying the WiFi login portal.

You might still need to follow the suggestions listed above in order for this to be successful (since I had completed them prior to attempting this solution).

I found this solution from a [blog post](https://poweruser.blog/macos-catalina-wifi-issue-captive-portal-broken-45610cc016b5) that has a more in depth solution for automatically triggering this process automatically until Apple releases a fix. But since it's not that difficult to manually open the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app` application I decided not to go through the entire workaround process.

---

**Edit**: it's important to note that not all networks will require this solution. In some cases just navigating to a non SSL site (examples provided in original question), will work just fine and show the login page. But if you get an error message about not being connected to the internet, this is a good thing to try.

Comment: This worked but I had to click on `Captive Network Assistant.app` a bunch of times while macOS was dithering with the connection. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

One of the reasons can be the custom added DNS configuration.

1. Go to System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS
2. Save your DNS list to somewhere else.
3. Remove these DNSs using the "-" button.
4. Reconnect Wi-Fi

> At this level, if that was the root cause of connection problem, you
> should see automatically retrieved local IPs for DNSs. Not exactly but
> something like: [image]

5. Enter your username / password for wifi connection landing page
6. Again go to the System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS
7. Reconfigure the previously removed DNSs from the list that you saved at step (2)

Unfortunately this method needs to be repeated each time when you try to connect.

PS: My scenario was related with Big Sur.

Reference: https://zapier.com/blog/open-wifi-login-page/

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me after removing the DNS entries was unchecking the "Limit IP tracking" box in the network settings: [image]

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything and much searching I realized my problem was Sophos. Even if you are not allowed to disable it properly, they have admitted the flaw and created a way of temporarily disabling it to get at captive internet, via the seven steps here.

As of Feb 2023, on macOS Monterey:

> 1. Open the local Sophos Endpoint UI
> 2. Click About in the lower right corner
> 3. Click Run Diagnostic Tool
> 4. Click Captive Portal Mode on the left side
> 5. Click Enable at the top
> 6. Enter your administrator credentials [this is a local password, not the secret tamper protection password]
> 7. This will turn off network interceptions for 5 minutes or until you click Disable (whichever comes first).

<sup>Source: [Advisory: Sophos Central Endpoint for Mac - Unable to connect to Public Wi-Fi networks on macOs Monterey (12)](https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000044202?language=en_US)</sup>

After this, I turned wifi off and on again, and it picked up the login screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Hello, Sam. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/333250)

Comment: Thanks @agarza,  I've done this.

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked was to log into the wifi of the hotel with my phone, and then set up a hot spot from my phone, connect with my MacBook Catalina and open the default browser. It surprisingy reached the wifi access webpage (although internet was technically going through from my phone) and I entered the information, checked the box for consent and accepted. I had access to internet. I then proceeded to connect directly to the wifi of the hotel and it worked. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

No answer on this thread worked for me while trying to log in to a network on a Deutsche Bahn ICE. What did was entering the router address in a browser.

As of Dec 2023 on macOS Sonoma 14.1.2 it can be found unter System Settings -> Network -> three dots for your network -> Details -> Router.

After entering the router address i got redirected to the login page.